# barra de progresso para a execução ao trocar de aba em javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com problema na barra de progresso feita em javascript, a barra esta funcionando mas o problema é, quando se troca de aba e depois volta a barra fica parada e volta a funcionar, gostaria de saber como fazer pra a barra continuar sendo executada ao trocar de pagina e depois voltar.

```js
    function progress() {
      var prg = document.getElementById('progress');
      var progresso = 500;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 150);

      function frame() {
        if (progresso == 10) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          progresso -= 5;
          if (prg.style.width = progresso + 'px' == 10 + 'px') {
            alert('termino');
          }
          prg.style.width = progresso + 'px';
        }
      }
    }
    progress();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
}

.progress-bar {
  width: 506px;
  height: 26px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 13px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.progress {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="br">
<head>
  <title>Progress Bar Demo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="progress-bar">
    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```